# How can i get the facebook post id?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, json.net, facebook-c#-sdk

How can i extract the post id after posting it using the Facebook method **Post()** or **PostTaskAsync()** ??

i am using `JSON.Net` like this

```
var postObject = await fb.PostTaskAsync("/me/feed", postArgs);               
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject((string)postObject);
string id = result.id;
```

but it doesn't work !

What is the appropriate way to do it using `facebook c# sdk v 6.x`?

Comment: var postObject = await fb.PostTaskAsync("/me/feed", postArgs);

dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject((string)postObject);

string id = result.id;

Comment: and i am using json.net

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error?  If so, what is it?  If not, what does the JSON look like?  In other words, what is in `postObject` after you call `PostTaskAsync`?

Comment: Can we know the value of `postObject` after `await` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to deserialize the response to use it the way you want to just do this

```
dynamic postObject = await fb.PostTaskAsync("/me/feed", postArgs);    
string id = postObject.id;
```

I haven't used the PostTackAsync either, is it possible that postObject is not filled yet when you are trying to read it ? I would try just a regular Post `fb.Post("/me/feed", postArgs)`  and see if that works.

if that doesn't solve it then you are going to have to set a break point and read the actual response.  It is possible you don't have the right permissions and you are getting some type of error back.  If this doesn't work for you - can you post the actual response that you are getting and it will be a lot easier to help

Comment: Yes sir, it worked just fine,,, I just didn't realize they were going to give me an object containing the respond fields just that easy :D
and the await keyword awaits whats after it so its kind of thread safe to use it and the execution is completed after the call to the async method completes and a return value is obtained.